# Why not messaging by 2 segues between views but a segue and a deletation

Tags: ios, delegates, segue

I'm very confused about this design patterns and I believe I didn't get all the points at the moment.

Let's put a simple scenario here:

Two views, say A and B, data passing through a segue from A to B. But when B want to pass data back to A or change/update some data which is belong to A's data source, a delegate is used here!. ***Why not just make 2 segues and let them pass the data***?

**My understanding is**:

Segue is a "hard" connection, controller A builds the connection to Controller B by a segue means it must knows controller B, therefore, A is retain the reference to B. On the other hand, the delegate is a "lose" connection from B to A, so B don't know much about A. As a result A to B is "Hard" connection, B to A is "lose" connection this can avoid memory leak problem.

**Question1**: Is any there errors in my understanding?

**Question2**: Is any other reasons to use segue and delegate pattern?

**Question3**: If delegate is so nice, why not use 2 delegates for all data passing and messaging?

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Segues aren't about passing data, they're about showing view controllers.  Sometimes you have to pass data to the destination view controller as part of that process but it isn't the reason you use a segue.

Comment: @dan thanks dan, I think I misunderstand the segue usage

Answer (score 1):

> Is any there errors in my understanding?

Your suggestion that segue assumes a hard connection is not accurate. One could build a segue that programs to a protocol implementation on the receiving end, rather than a specific class. This is perfectly legal, and makes your code more flexible.

> Is there any other reasons to use segue and delegate pattern?

By design, segue API is not symmetric: the sender gets a notification when the segue is about to fire, but the receiver simply gets opened. Therefore, it is the task of the sender to pass whatever is needed to the receiver to establish a way for it to communicate back to the sender.

> If delegate is so nice, why not use 2 delegates for all data passing and messaging?

You could absolutely use a delegate for communicating both sides. However, the asymmetry of the API makes it unnecessary to use the first delegate.

Answer (score 1):

> Question1: Is any there errors in my understanding?

No, it's correct most of the times.

> Question3: If delegate is so nice, why not use 2 delegates for all data passing and messaging?
>   ]

Good question with a TL;DR answer : one of the two objects has to retain the other and it's easier and meaningful to do it that way.

---

Let's continue talking only about ViewControllers, even if the process could be true with any objects...
The parent view controller has to know the child. The logic matters to the parent, it needs to know which child to call on which action.

The child doesn't have to care how its presented, it can be in a container view, pushed in a navigation controller, presented modally... It doesn't have to bother. But if it wants to communicate with the caller, whoever it is, well, using delegation makes sense.

You could have a *dual delegation*, but you would need an intermediate object, being the delegate of both controllers, having the responsibility to pass the right message at the right controller. Also, both objects would have to be retained somewhere. Could lead to a few useful cases, but most of the times having one strong dependency is enough.

Also, you don't ***have*** to use delegation. For example you could have a `parentViewController` property on the `ChildViewController`, and you'd set the property like this in the parent's `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let childVC = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
       childVC.parentVC = self
    }
}
```

But now you would have a strong coupling, which means :

- potential retain cycles (as child also retains parent), you have to think about setting the parent to `weak`
- less reusability for the child view, as it needs a very specific parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation